# Return to app state after receiving call android/ios phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova-3, phone-call

I have developed one phonegap/cordova(3.2) based mobile app for android and ios platforms.
First screen of the app is login page. Suppose we have logged into the app and we are in middle of the app then suddenly we receive a call from some number and we receive it.
After call ends the app is getting automatically redirected to Login page.I want to keep the app where it was before receiving call.

Please provide me some solution to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>` in `config.xml`